# Как добавить новый тип данных?

Tags: flutter, dart, localstorage

Всем привет, пишу по статье из интернета, в которой рассказывается, как добавлять и читать с локального хранилища (shared_preferences). Так вот, есть файл с добавлением и чтением данных, выглядит он так -

```
static saveData<T>(String key, T value) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    switch (T) {
      case String:
        prefs.setString(key, value as String);
        break;
      case int:
        prefs.setInt(key, value as int);
        break;
      case bool:
        prefs.setBool(key, value as bool);
        break;
      // case stringList:
      //   prefs.setStringList(key, <String>[] as stringList);
      //   break;
      case double:
        prefs.setDouble(key, value as double);
        break;
    }
```

Подскажите, как пожалуйста добавить сюда вот этот метод - `await prefs.setStringList('items', <String>['Earth', 'Moon', 'Sun']);`

А также, как реализовать удаление? Вот моя попытка -

```
static Future<T> removeData<T>(String key) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      return prefs.remove(key) as T;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В dart есть ключевое слово `typdef` для объявления ссылки на тип.
Пример использования: `typedef StringList = List<String>;`

В вашем случае это будет выглядеть так:

```
typedef StringList = List<String>;

class A extends StatelessWidget {
  static void saveData<T>(String key, T value) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    switch (T) {
      case String:
        prefs.setString(key, value as String);
        break;
      case int:
        prefs.setInt(key, value as int);
        break;
      case bool:
        prefs.setBool(key, value as bool);
        break;
      case StringList:
        prefs.setStringList(key, value as StringList);
        break;
      case double:
        prefs.setDouble(key, value as double);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Эту функцию можно вызывать раличными способами:

```
saveData<StringList>('key', []);
saveData<List<String>>('key', []);
saveData('key', <String>[]);
```

Удаление значения из хранилища:

```
/// Возвращает true в случае успеха
static Future<bool> removeData(String key) async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  return prefs.remove(key);
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: А можете что-нибудь сказать про удаление?

Comment: @Daniil 
prefs.remove(key); Возвращает true в случае успеха

Comment: The method 'remove' isn't defined for the type 'bool'. (Documentation)  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'remove'. Ответ на `prefs.remove("header");`